# How to set env variable in windows?

Tags: windows

I followed this tutorial.
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html

but unfortunately, it doesn't seem working.

```
(payo-py3.10) PS C:\Users\ser> set MY_VAR=abc
(payo-py3.10) PS C:\Users\ser> python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('MY_VAR'))"
None
(payo-py3.10) PS C:\Users\ser> set MY_VAR
```

how do I set the env var with command line?

Answer (score 0):

You are following a tutorial for `cmd`, not powershell. In powershell `set` is a shorthand for `set-varaible` which creates a "local" variable which is not inherited by child processes (like python in your case). The following works though:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\FlyingTeller> $ENV:MY_VAR='abc'
(base) PS C:\Users\FlyingTeller> python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('MY_VAR'))"
abc
(base) PS C:\Users\FlyingTeller> MY_VAR='abc'
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to obtain system environment variables in the Conda virtual environment through the os. environment. get ("my_var") method.  We need to separately set the environment variables for the current environment of Conda.

```
conda env config vars set my_var=value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm using poetry venv. not conda.

Comment: I don't know where you got this information, but it is false